# How do I convert IPA files to project files that can be run on iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

Can anyone please tell me how to convert the downloaded .IPA files (Apps) to project file to run on iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use iTune to run a .ipa file. But iTunes can be used to run .ipa files on devices only.

Answer (score 1):

To shed some light on the why: The iPhone has an ARM processor, but the simulator runs on a i386 processor. And you can't run code that was compiled for one processor family on the other processor.

If you could run ARM program in the simulator there would be no reason to compile different code for the device and the simulator. But this is what we all do each day.

Answer (score 0):

ipa files contains the compiled source code. You can't open them as project. Besides you can't run any ipa using iPhone simulator.